# Using JMX for Starting/Stopping Gateways/Services from Web Page

Tags: java, spring, jmx, mbeans, adaptor

I am a beginner in JMX and looking for ways to implement the title. I am working on a big project so it will not be possible for me to make the interface and declare methods of the whole project which I need to do for making Mbeans. Also, I want to start by initializing the built-in JMX server(Mbean Server, once I create the MBeans) instead of using tomcat. I want to do this without using Jconsole as its kinda requirement. Thanks.

An implementation which I am planning kindly give your thoughts:

1. I am planning to make Mbeans(which I am unsure how to implement for projects which have so many services and gateways).
2. Registering them to Mbean Server which comes as part of the Java 6+
3. Find Suitable Adaptor(Kindly suggest if you have any idea)
4. Get the results on the browser using HTML/Http.

Comment: There is no build in JMX server... So you have to use the tomcat one. I strongly suggest a read of the JMX chapter in both Spring and Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hi, thanks for the help. But I want to know is there any way by which I can make Mbeans for big Industry system as there are so many classes and methods and use Mbean Server later on. Also, we are using legacy spring .So, I will definitely look into  the suggestion which you gave.

Comment: I assumed you are already using Spring Boot if not just read the JMX chapter in the [Spring reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jmx). They provide several options to do so.

Comment: No , we are not using spring-boot...we are just using spring. Thanks I will look into the link.